# Nodejs within Grails app

Tags: node.js, grails, reactjs

Sorry if I come off as a novice. I am front end dev. I am going to work on creating new mobile views in a grails app. I am planning to use Reactjs for the front end development but I am not sure if or how can I use Nodejs within the Grails app. I am not a grail dev, hence the question. Any practical advice or links that can help me understand how node works with Grails will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. That would work too :)

Comment: What benefit are you seeking by using Grails instead of something else? Is Grails basically going to be a way to serve static content and provide an API for ReactJS to use?

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't make much sense. React is a front end framework which can work with any back end framework that can create the data in a format it uses and process its requests. But Grails and Node.js are back end frameworks and are based on completely different underlying infrastructure. Grails works on the JVM and Node.js uses V8.

Technically yes, you can use Node.js in the JVM, using Nashorn, but it's currently slower than using it natively and doesn't support all of the features of native Node.js.

You can partition your back end into multiple parts though, and implement each in whatever tech you wish (Grails, Spring, Node.js, Rails, Python, etc.) You could go the full microservice route, or just write them in a way that each part does a focused subset of the overall functionality and implement the necessary communication between them.

Comment: Ah. This is starting to make sense. For some reason I had in my mind that I need NodeJS to make ReactJS work. Now thinking about it, I am wondering why I thought so.